# How do I get a switch statement to loop back into a menu

Tags: c++

Hey everyone I'm currently having some trouble in making the switch statement coming back out around to the start of the menu. Instead it proceeds into another main function that I don't want it to unless the user chooses the right selection.

here's the code I have anyway:

```
int main() 
{
int choice;
bool menu = true;
cout <<"Please select one of the following options:  \n";

cout << "1: Play\n"
        "2: Help\n"
        "3: Config\n"
        "4: Quit\n";

cout << "Enter your selection (1, 2,3 or 4): ";
cin >> choice;
//*****************************************************************************
// Switch menu to display the menu.
//*****************************************************************************
    if(menu)
    {

      switch (choice)
     {
          case 1:
            cout << "You have chosen play";
            break;
         case 2:
            cout << "You have chosen help\n";
            cout << "Here is a description of the game Hangman and how it is played:\nThe word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, giving the number of letters, numbers and category. If the guessing player suggests a letter or number which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions";
            break; 
         case 3:
            cout << "You have chosen config";
            break;
             case 4:
            cout << "You have chosen Quit, Goodbye.";
            break;
        default:
            cout<< "Your selection must be between 1 and 4!\n";

    }

        }    
getchar();
getchar();


cout << "You missed " << playGame("programming");
cout << " times to guess the word programming." << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `do while` loop like this:

```
int main() 
{
int choice;
bool menu = true;
do{
cout <<"Please select one of the following options:  \n";

cout << "1: Play\n"
    "2: Help\n"
    "3: Config\n"
    "4: Quit\n";

cout << "Enter your selection (1, 2,3 or 4): ";
cin >> choice;
//*****************************************************************************
// Switch menu to display the menu.
//*****************************************************************************
    switch (choice)
 {
      case 1:
        cout << "You have chosen play";
       int missed = playgame('programming');
        break;
     case 2:
        cout << "You have chosen help\n";
        cout << "Here is a description of the game Hangman and how it is    played:\nThe      word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, giving the number of letters, numbers and category. If the guessing player suggests a letter or number which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions";
        break; 
     case 3:
        cout << "You have chosen config";
        break;
         case 4:
        cout << "You have chosen Quit, Goodbye.";
        break;
    default:
        cout<< "Your selection must be between 1 and 4!\n";

    }

}while(choice!=4);    
getchar();
getchar();


cout << "You missed " << playGame("programming");
cout << " times to guess the word programming." << endl;
```

}

I have added the do loop before you display your menu  so that everytime the user chooses a choice, the user is displayed the menu again unless the user enters 4, in which case , the program comes out of the do while loop.
You can call the function playgame() in case 1..I have edited my answer to include playgame();

Comment: Ok so I have an earlier function called int playGame(); Would I just call the function in Case 1: or is there some other method to get the code to play the game? Sorry i'm pretty confused right now.

Comment: @user2857301 you can call the function in case 1 as shown above

Answer (score 2):

You could replace your `if` with a `while` loop

```
cout << "Enter your selection (1, 2, 3 or 4): ";
while (menu)
{
    cin >> choice;
    menu = false;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "You have chosen play";
        break;
    ....
    default:
        cout<< "Your selection must be between 1 and 4!\n";
        menu = true; // incorrect input, run loop again
}
```